# How to set form-group background color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to set the background color on form-group. To clarify what I exactly mean, look at the following picture
[image: form group]
As you can see above that I marked the div with color, I want to set the background color from form-group.

I tried with the following css.

```
.signup-ctrl {

  //margin-top: 60px;

  .form-buffer {
    margin: 30px 0px;
    background-color: #006dcc;

  }
}
```

and the html

```
  <div class="col-md-5 portfolio-item">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group form-buffer">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-buffer">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-buffer">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="emailconfirm" placeholder="Enter email confirmation">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-buffer">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter your Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group form-buffer">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="captcha" placeholder="Enter numbers from image">
      </div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign Up</button>
    </form>

  </div>
```

But it does not work, what do I wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your `.form-group` takes up exactly the same height as the `input` inside of it so every background color you add to it is actually hidden behind the input.

You could replace the top/bottom margins with padding to make the `.form-group` area actually bigger than the `input`:

```
.form-group {
  padding: 30px 0;
  background-color: #006dcc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is incorrect, it should be:

```
.portfolio-item form .form-buffer.form-group {
margin: 30px 0px;
background-color: #006dcc;
}
```

this will select the whole `.form-group`. Your mistake was nesting a CSS rule inside another.

[Here is a fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/alexwcoleman/zvec393u/)

Comment: It does not work. Additionally I use the bootstrap theme yeti, it is the reason, why does not work?

Comment: perhaps your CSS needs to be more specific. I've edited my answer.

Comment: wait, are you meaning that you want background colour in the actual input box?

Comment: I want to change the bankground color of `div class="form-group`.

Comment: yes I did and still does not work. But margin works like a charm.

Comment: then there must be some deeper CSS specificity that isn't apparent through your code sample... I've updated my answer again, try that exact snippet. Make sure that the CSS in my answer isn't inside another CSS rule like you have in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds strange..!! but it doesnt work like that you have apply `padding-bottom: XXpx` inside the `form-group` of your choice instead of applying just `background-color`, and then it works for the length that you applied in the `padding-bottom`.